# Can't set headers after they are sent when trying to redirect after using Google's oauth2Client.getToken()

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

After receiving oauth2 tokens from google I am trying to redirect to an endpoint on my express server to make api requests.

This is the flow of the auth requests:

```
app.get('/api/presentation/getpresentation/:id', function(req, res, next){
  req.session.user = req.user.id;
  req.session.presentation_id = req.params.id;
  res.redirect(google_auth_url)
});

app.get('/oauth2callback', function(req, res) {
  const code = req.query.code;
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    req.session.tokens = tokens;
    if (!err) {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      res.redirect(`/api/presentation/${req.session.presentation_id}`);
      return;
    }
    res.status(500).send(err);
  })  
});

app.get('/api/presentation/:id', **do things with api consent**);
```

The error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.location (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:884:15)
at ServerResponse.redirect (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:922:18)
at /Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/server/index.js:112:11
at /Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:154:5
at Request._callback (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:106:7)
at Request.self.callback (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1057:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been tearing my hair out on this one for a while!

Thanks!

Comment: What line is `at /Users/joe/school/solo-project/present/server/index.js:112:11` in your snippet?

Comment: It's the res.redirect(`/api/presentation/${req.session.presentation_id}`);

Comment: Which oauth2 client library are you using?

Comment: Does `oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens)` already send a response?

Comment: I'm using the googleapis library. I don't think setCredentials sends a response. I was thinking getToken() might but I'm not one hundred percent sure.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found the issue. I wasn't returning done(null, user) when I was deserializing my user which was causing the subsequent done(null, false) to be executed as well. The strange thing is this configuration was working when I made the google api call from the same route as my user log in. Not sure if I'll ever understand that but I'm just happy it is fixed.